# SQL value of a row as column name

Tags: sql, create-table

I would like to consider possibilities of making the following thing:

```
create table customers
(
    ID int identity,
    name varchar(50)
)

create table additional
(
    ID int identity,
    customer_id int references customers(ID),
    input_name varchar(50),
    input_value varchar(50)
)
```

It should be able to define name and value of additional input for a particular customer and display it in a column. Example:

```
insert into customers (name) values ("aaa");
insert into additional (customer_id,input_name,input_value) values (1,"last name","bbb");
```

Now the result that I need is:

```
customerID | first name | last name
-----------------------------------
1          | aaa        | bbb
```

so that additional field is displayed as column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy if you are happy with a static query:

```
SELECT c.customerID, a2.input_value AS first_name, a1.input_value AS last_name
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN additional a1 ON a1.ID = c.ID and a1.input_name = 'last name'
LEFT JOIN additional a2 ON a2.ID = c.ID and a2.input_name = 'first name'
```

If you are not happy with a static query, this means that the number and the names of the columns will change with the data. So in this case, you will have to dynamically construct your query.